# how to know the installed version of a library by macports

Tags: macports

I've installed opencv via macports. I would like to know the version of the library through macports. Is there any option that allows me to acquire the installed version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for version information from the installed version of opencv you can use `port installed opencv`. The result might contain more than one line if you have multiple versions of opencv installed.